# Prevent the creation of routes from components and public folders in the pages folder. And deny access to see files in public folders. NextJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I have NextJs application with a custom server where I have customized a route. Where I show the template depending on the hostname and pathname.

My server.js

```
const next = require('next');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { parse } = require('url');
const dev = process.env.ENV === 'local';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const port = 3000;

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(async (req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

    const pathnameFromServer = 'test_path_name';
    const templateFromServer = 'template1';

    if (pathname === `/${pathnameFromServer}`) {
      await app.render(req, res, `/${templateFromServer}`, query);
    } else {
      await handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
  });
});
```

I am creating a template in the pages folder. And I want to create the components, public folder in it. Like this.

[image]

But NextJs build everything in the pages folder as routes.

My next.config.js

```
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['@nfs-react/components']);

module.exports = withTM({
  useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,
});
```

I need to prevent the creation of routes from components and public folders in the pages folder. I also need to deny access to see files in public folders.

Answer (score 1):

You can name the `/pages` folder something else, so Next.js will ignore it.

Comment: A good idea! But then the routes are not created at all :(

404...

Comment: Error: > Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root

Comment: @Grigri, you can leave `/pages` empty. Add your routes to some other directory. Keep `useFileSystemPublicRoutes` as `false` in the config file.

If the custom routes are not created check the custom server script whether it defines routes correctly.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. But besides 404 nothing more was created.

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/65594153/85734445-b9507a00-b705-11ea-9540-30a314dfd6e1.png
@nikolai-kiselev
This is what misleads me. But everything works as I want.
What do you think? Does this add extra code to the build?

Comment: @Grigri, even if `useFileSystemPublicRoutes` set to false, the pages inside `/pages` still will be generated. So you need to remove all files from this folder.

Comment: I can’t find how to specify the pathname folder outside the pages folder.

because app.render() pathname sees at the pagesDir level.

Comment: @Grigri, see example https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server

Comment: app.render (req, res, '/ b', query) - where '/ b' is the path in the folder pages. But this, unfortunately, does not fit. @nikolai-kiselev